# Yii2 роутинг на сайте c поддоменами

Tags: php, yii2, yii

Я хочу реализовать на своём сайте города на поддоменах. И в зависимости от города показывать нужную информацию.

Поддомены будут вида:

ufa.site.com

moskva.site.com

Для получения названия города из поддомена реализовал правила вида:

```
'//<city:\w+>.<hostname:[^\/]+>.<domain:[^\/]+>/' => 'site/index'
```

В тоже время на сайте будут страницы содержание которых будет независимо от текущего поддомена. Например страница /about. И таких страниц будет много.

Каким образом мне сделать так чтоб при открытии сайта, например через ufa.site.com,
ссылка на страницу about осталась вида  http://site.com/about.

Сейчас она получается в таком виде:

```
Url::to(['site/about'], true) > http:://ufa.site.com/about.
```

UPD:

Это будет работать если в правилах жестко указать название домена

```
'//site.com/about' => 'site/about'
```

Хотелось бы так не хардкодить а писать просто:

```
'//<hostname>.<domain>/about' => 'site/about'
```

В то же время есть обратный момент. При переходе на страницу

```
http:://site.com/about
```

Некоторые ссылки должны по-прежнему содержать название города.
Например ссылка на логотипе для возврата на главную страницу должна остаться вида

```
http:://ufa.site.com
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил вопрос написав свой UrlManager.